# Unknown Error using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads

I'm meeting a problem with this code which is a basic code from my books to help understand how the threads works. It's is supposed to create NTHREADS which should execute the `neg` function and then return the opposite of the argument received

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NTHREADS 2

void *neg (void * param);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    int arg [NTHREADS];
    int err;

    long i;
    for(i = 0; i< NTHREADS; i++){
        arg[i] = i;
        err= pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, &neg, (void *) &(arg[i]));

        if(err =! 0){
        error(err,"pthread_create");
        }
    }

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < NTHREADS; j++){
        int *r;
        err= pthread_join(threads[j], (void **) &r);
        printf("Resultat [%d] = %d \n", j, *r);

        free(r);
        if(err!=0){
        error(err,"pthread_join");
        }
    }
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *neg (void * param){
    int *l;
    l= (int *) param;
    int *r= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *r = -*l;
    return ((void *) r);
}
```

When compiling I receive this message:

```
nico@nico-G56JR:~/Desktop$ gcc -pthread Threads.c
nico@nico-G56JR:~/Desktop$ ./a.out
./a.out: c: Unknown error 4196644
```

I can't find the mistake, can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you compiling it and then executing it in two steps, or one?  Looks like the problem is with the execution.

Comment: where is the definition for threads? you are simply creating threads. but what those are doing. where it is defined?

Answer (score 3):

This

```
 if(err =! 0){
```

should be

```
 if(err != 0){
```

It is a bit of bad luck really, because err =! 0 actually compiles, assigning err a not zero value, which then falls into the error case passing something into the error function that is not really meaningful for your code.

Comment: Is that why it's reporting `unknown error`?  Should it report `pthread_create error`?

Comment: Looking at the error manpage, it looks like the OP is passing the wrong arguments to error as well:  void error(int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...);